# Dates broken out by month and days of week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with datetime column ranging over many years, I would like to know if some days of the week are busier than others (e.g. is does Monday see more activities that say Friday). same for months (e.g. is July more busy than December). Also would like to get the std deviation of those counts to see how much variation there is.

So if I have a datetime column called activityDate, how would I break down and get the daily and monthly counts and std deviations?

using SQL Server 2012

Thanks

Comment: Use the datepart function, and then group by DayOfWeek, Month, Year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  mon, cnt, STDEV(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY mon)
FROM    (
        SELECT  DATEPART(month, activityDate) mon, COUNT(*) cnt
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                DATEPART(month, activityDate)
        ) q

SELECT  wd, cnt, STDEV(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY wd)
FROM    (
        SELECT  DATEPART(weekday, activityDate) wd, COUNT(*) cnt
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                DATEPART(weekday, activityDate)
        ) q
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried the first query, gave me the error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'q.mon' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `datename()` function from msdn: [Datename](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDQQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms174395.aspx&ei=GdySVdvdBMHuoATDnI7gDg&usg=AFQjCNF86wWp7FL-g9utGOPjZD8WYKq9uw&sig2=tWLQGdpUqQ_Z493tzzohNQ&bvm=bv.96783405,d.cGU)

```
select datename(dw,getdate()),datename(m,getdate())
```